# Node.js FS - Offset is out of range, but also in range?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm attempting to read a file to memory using `Node.js` and receiving an out of range error for the `offset` though it falls within the required range. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Code snippet:

```
    let offset = 0;
    let length = 1024;
    let position = 0;
    let hex : Array<BinaryData> = [];

    let fd = fs.openSync(filepath, 'r+');
    //For each 1024 bytes
    for (let j = 0; j < fileSize / length; j++) {
        //Refresh the buffer and output for each iteration
        let buffer = new Int8Array(length);
        let output: number[] = [];

        //Read 1024 bytes
        let bytesRead = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);

        //Update offset and position for next iteration
        offset += bytesRead;
        position += bytesRead;

        //Convert to number[]
        for (var x in buffer) {
            output.push(Number.parseInt(x));
        }

        //Push to BinaryData array
        hex.push(new BinaryData(output));
    }
    fs.closeSync(fd);
```

The error received:

> rejected promise not handled within 1 second: RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 1024. Received 1024
>   extensionHostProcess.js:775
>   stack trace: RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 1024. Received 1024

1024 is clearly within the range of `>=0 && <= 1024` so I'm unsure where my error is. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to just read 1024 bytes into the same buffer over and over again, then don't advance the `offset` because that's the position into the buffer to start reading into it.  `position` is where to read from the file.  That you are properly advancing.

So, if you just want to read in the beginning of the buffer each time, then `offset` should stay at `0`.

I suspect the error is because you're exceeding the size of your buffer because you are advancing `offset` so that the `fs.readSync()` would fill past the end of the buffer and thus you get a RangeError.

Comment: Thank you! I was advancing the buffer which only has space for one read iteration. Keeping `offset` at `0` for the start of each iteration solves my issue. A small oversight that had me scratching my head.